# How to set image for UIImageView which is contained in NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray containing UIImageViews and NSArray containing UIImages. The arrays are of equal size. I need to set images from the second array to the first one. It would be very convinient to implement it in loop, something like:

```
for (int i = 0;i < firstArray.count;i++)
  [firstArray objectAtIndex:i].image = [secondArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

but that doesn't compile. It says "Property "image" not found on object of type "id". Is it possible to implement it in loop somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast from the `id` type to a `UIImageView` before accessing properties on it. Use the following...

```
for (int i = 0;i < firstArray.count;i++)
  ((UIImageView *)[firstArray objectAtIndex:i]).image = [secondArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if adding all of those round brackets makes it harder to read, (personally it draws my eye too much) you can do:

```
UIImageView *imageView = nil;

for (int i = 0;i < firstArray.count;i++) {
   imageView = [firstArray objectAtIndex:i];
   imageView.image = [secondArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0;i < firstArray.count;i++)
    [[firstArray objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[secondArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: how to add UIimageview object in NSarray objective c